# How are Attach Permissions Governed for Image Types

Tags: media-library, editor-user-permissions

We have some elevated users who occasionally need to update particular images in our system.  These images reside in our media library and the users (through their roles) have been granted every permission there I could find.  When they click the *Attach* link, though, they get an "Application access denied" error (as recorded in the log).  The can *Detach* fine, but not *Attach*.  Are there any insights as to what permissions might need to be applied and where to get this to work as expected?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are experiencing is related to this item:
`/sitecore/content/Applications/Dialogs/Upload`

The item has the following access by default:

[image: Example security]

Try overriding the security for this item.